# How can you add a column label to a data frame with a before, during, and after phase over time?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset where locations being treated with a chemical spray. What I would like to do is track the phase of when sites were treated such as pre-treatment (site was visited but not treated), active treatment (site treated on this day), and post-treatment (next visit after treatment - but not treated again).

I have tried doing this by using a for loop but I not sure how to perform the loop for each site individually. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample of what I am looking to accomplish:
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH88R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by site_id, instead of looping over it. Then, for each group, you find the index for when the treatment has occurred and you can use it to establish some conditions to add the correct "tag" (pre, active, post). There you go!

```
def func(g):
    idx = g.query('applied==1').index[0]
    g.loc[:idx-1, 'applied'] = 'pre'
    g.loc[idx, 'applied'] = 'active'
    g.loc[idx+1:, 'applied'] = 'post'
    return g

df.groupby('id').apply(func)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: However, one issue I have is that I get the following TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'. This is marked at the line g.loc[:idx-1, 'applied'] = 'pre'. Do you know what is going on here?

Comment: I tested on a simple dataframe that seemed similar to the image you shared: `df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'applied': [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]})`. Perhaps some property of yours breaks the code.

Comment: Also, note that I gave you a sample solution using groupby, which is a very useful tool. However, the logic in the code will break in some scenarios, such as the last row in your image. You should then edit the code where appropriate to obtain the desired result.